# Do Telepathic Talent and an elan's resistance stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

Do racial traits bonus stack?

> #### Telepathic Talent:
>
> **Benefit:** You can expend your psionic focus to gain a +2 trait bonus to your saves against mind-affecting powers and psi-like abilities. This talent grants no benefit if you do not have the ability to gain psionic focus.

and

> #### Elan
>
> **Resistance (Su):** Elans can use psionic energy to increase their resistance to various forms of attack. As an immediate action, an elan can spend 1 power point to gain a +4 racial bonus on saving throws until the beginning of her next action.

if I'm a elan (with focus), if is a mind-affecting power to resist, Can I use both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Telepathic Talent gives you a “trait” bonus, and the elan’s resistance gives you a “racial” bonus. These are not the same thing: “trait” ≠ “racial.” Since they are bonuses of different types, they stack. In situations where both apply, you add both bonuses together.

Comment: Ah yes, the good ol' "race trait" vs "racial trait" confusion.

Comment: Telepathic Talent is poorly worded, though: what kind of action (if any) does expending psionic focus take, and how long does the +2 trait bonus last? As worded, it's arguably equivalent to "Requirement: ability to psionically focus. Benefit: gain a +2 trait bonus on saves against mind-affecting powers and psi-like abilities.", unless there's something I missed in the base "psionic focus" rules.

Comment: @minnmass Correct, it should say you can expend psionic focus when you have to make such a save to get a bonus on that save. It wouldn’t use an action, though, so that part wouldn’t really be necessary (though being explicit can be nice).